# Express.js routers and new object instantiating

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

In most of examples authors used classes with static methods and passed that classes with static methods to router.

```
router.post('/user/name', (req, res, next) => {

    UserController.getName(req, res, next);
});

router.post('/user/surname', (req, res, next) => {

    UserController.getSurname(req, res, next);
});
```

Im not a fan of classes with static methods. And prefer to create instance.

```
router.post('/user/name', (req, res, next) => {

     new UserController(req, res, next).getName();
});

router.post('/user/surname', (req, res, next) => {

     new UserController(req, res, next).getSurname();
});
```

Lets imagine we have 1000 calls to `/user/surname`. So as I'm understand 1000 objects of `UserController` will be created (and then they will be destroyed by GC as unusable). Is that right? If yes, maybe will be better to use static methods cause they were created just once on class loading?

Comment: It's hard to understand what your asking, you answered your own question, yes "I'm understand 1000 objects of UserController will be created (and then they will be destroyed by GC as unusable)"

Comment: "*Im not a fan of classes with static methods*" - then don't make them `class`es. Use plain object literals. Or just module-level function declarations. "*I prefer to create instance*" - why, what are you doing with these objects? Will they keep any state? Will they have lots of utility methods? At least share common values between multiple methods? If no, then OOP is unnecessary, and you should use a plain procedure instead. "*I understand 1000 objects will be created*" - yes, that's right, but this is not a performance sensitive part of your code, one more or less per request doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

> So as I'm understand 1000 objects of `UserController` will be created (and then they will be destroyed by GC as unusable). Is that right?

Yes, that is correct.

> If yes, maybe will be better to use static methods cause they were created just once on class loading?

Yes.  Static methods are basically just functions that are give to you as a property on an object.  There is no reason to avoid them.  You should just be thinking of them as function calls where the function name is namespaced onto an object.  Surely, you don't feel like your Javascript should avoid all function calls.  And, all that's needed here is a function call.  In general, you should avoid creating an object that is just going to be used for one method call and then garbage collected because it's unnecessary overhead.

---

FYI, if you really don't want to use static methods on a class, you can just declare a plain object and put your methods as properties on that object:

```
let obj = {
     method1: function() {},
     method2: function() {}
};

obj.method1();
```

Comment: @sever - Did this answer your question? If so, you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer. That will also earn you some reputation points here on stackoverflow for following the proper procedure. If this didn't answer your question, please comment about which part of your question you're still confused about.